# Error in merging two sequences of timestamps to yield strings

Tags: f#, functional-programming, f#-interactive

The code sorts two input sequences - seq01 and seq02 - on the basis of their `timestamp` values and returns a sequence that denotes which sequence is to be read for the values to be in order.

For cases where seq02's timestamp value is lesser than seq01's timestamp value we yield a "2" to the sequence being returned, else a "1". These denote whether at that point seq01 is to be taken or seq02 is to be taken for the data to be in order (by timestamp value).

```
let mergeSeq (seq01:seq<_>)  (seq02:seq<_>) = 
    seq { 
            use iter01 = seq01.GetEnumerator()
            use iter02 = seq02.GetEnumerator() 
            while iter01.MoveNext() do
                let _,_,time01 = iter01.Current
                let _,_,time02 = iter02.Current 
                while time02 < time01 && iter02.MoveNext()  do 
                    yield "2"
                yield "1"
    }
```

To test it in the FSI created two sequences a and b, a={1;3;5;...} and b={0;2;4;...}. So the expected values for `let c = mergeSeq a b` would have been {"2","1","2","1"...}. However I am getting this error: `error FS0001: The type ''a * 'b * 'c' does not match the type 'int'`

**EDIT**

After correcting:

```
let mergeSeq (seq01:seq<_>)  (seq02:seq<_>) = 
    seq { 
            use iter01 = seq01.GetEnumerator()
            use iter02 = seq02.GetEnumerator() 
            while iter01.MoveNext() do
                let time01 = iter01.Current
                let time02 = iter02.Current 
                while time02 < time01 && iter02.MoveNext()  do 
                    yield "2"
                yield "1"
    }
```

After running this, there's another error: `call MoveNext`. Somehow the iteration is not being performed.

**EDIT 2**

```
let mergeRef (seq01:seq<_>) (seq02:seq<_>) = 
    seq{
            use iter01 = seq01.GetEnumerator()
            use iter02 = seq02.GetEnumerator()
            iter01.MoveNext() 
            iter02.MoveNext() 

            let temp01 = ref iter01.Current  //!!using mutable reference
            let temp02 = ref iter02.Current
            
            while iter01.MoveNext() do
                while (iter02.MoveNext()) && ((!temp02) < (!temp01)) do
                    temp02 := iter02.Current
                    yield "2"
                yield "1" 
                temp01 := iter01.Current

            //if seq01 finishes before seq02
            while iter02.MoveNext() do
                yield "2"

       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the edit...

You need to call MoveNext on 2 before accessing current.  You're not updating time02 as you move through 2 in the inner loop.  And you're not checking for the end of sequences properly (e.g. if 2 ends but 1 is going, you'll try to access 2 after the end).

(Is this homework?)

Comment: thanks. and not homework: i'm reworking some of the stuff I coded in C using F# to be familiar with functional programming.

Comment: could you please elaborate on where to give the MoveNext()? the inner loop does have the MoveNext() in the 'while' line

Comment: I don't know how to say it clearer.  You are accessing iter02.Current before you have called iter02.MoveNext().  You have to call MoveNext() first.

Comment: that part was clear. have changed code, working. thanks for being patient enough. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
let _,_,time01 = iter01.Current
let _,_,time02 = iter02.Current
```

to

```
let time01 = iter01.Current
let time02 = iter02.Current
```

so that the code is type-checked with `seq<int>`.

I don't understand your intention. If you want to compare each corresponding pair of elements in two sequences, there are more functional solutions:

```
let mergeSeq seq01 seq02 = 
    Seq.map2 (fun s1 s2 -> if s2 < s1 then "2" else "1") seq01 seq02
```

If you want to merge two sorted sequences, using `GetEnumerator` is fine but returning `"2"` and `"1"` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: there was some file I/O involved, as well as fairly large chunks of data along with the timestamps. wanted to keep the "1", "2" as indicators of which sequence to read from in order to the final (next) merging step (not shown).

Comment: `seq{}` is lazy and it builds up computation, not data so you shouldn't worry. Maybe you should describe your real use case.

Answer (score 2):

You have written code as if

```
a={1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3...}
```

just use

```
            let time01 = iter01.Current
            let time02 = iter02.Current
```

Comment: thanks. immediate problem solved, but still getting an error at runtime. question has been duly edited.